# I want to make a delegated class use properties of the class that delegates it in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, delegates, composition

I have these two classes:

```
class InfoDayViewModel(
    day: Day,
    application: Application
) : DayViewModel(day, application) {
    val dayDeleted = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply { value = false }
    fun deleteDay() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.deleteDay(day)
            dayDeleted.value = true
        }
    }
}

class InfoIdeaViewModel(
    idea: Idea,
    topic: Topic,
    application: Application
) : IdeaViewModel(idea, topic, application) {
    val ideaDeleted = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply { value = false }
    fun deleteIdea() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.deleteIdea(idea)
            ideaDeleted.value = true
        }
    }
}
```

They are very similar but I can't use a superclass because they already have superclasses. So I can create an interface like this one:

```
interface InfoItemViewModel {
    val itemDeleted: MutableLiveData<Boolean>
    fun deleteItem()
}
```

However, I will have to implement the functionality of the interfaces in both classes and I will have to repeat the code. So I can use composition and create a class that contains the implementation of the interface:

```
abstract class InfoItemViewModelImpl(private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope) : InfoItemViewModel {
    override val itemDeleted = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply { value = false }
    override fun deleteItem() {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            deleteItemFromDatabase()
            itemDeleted.value = true
        }
    }
    abstract suspend fun deleteItemFromDatabase()
}
```

And I can make both classes implement this functionality like that:

```
class InfoIdeaViewModel(
    idea: Idea, topic: Topic, application: Application
) : IdeaViewModel(idea, topic, application), InfoItemViewModel {
    private val infoItemViewModel = object : InfoItemViewModelImpl(viewModelScope) {
        override suspend fun deleteItemFromDatabase() { repository.deleteIdea(idea) }
    }
    override val itemDeleted get() = infoItemViewModel.itemDeleted
    override fun deleteItem() { infoItemViewModel.deleteItem() }
}

class InfoDayViewModel(
    day: Day, application: Application
) : DayViewModel(day, application), InfoItemViewModel {
    private val infoItemViewModel = object : InfoItemViewModelImpl(viewModelScope) {
        override suspend fun deleteItemFromDatabase() { repository.deleteDay(day) }
    }
    override val itemDeleted get() = infoItemViewModel.itemDeleted
    override fun deleteItem() { infoItemViewModel.deleteItem() }
}
```

However, there is a lot of boilerplate code because in every class I have to create an object that contains the implementation and for every property and function make it use the object.

To solve this I thought about delegation like this:

```
class InfoDayViewModel(
    day: Day, application: Application
) : DayViewModel(day, application), InfoItemViewModel by object : InfoItemViewModelImpl(viewModelScope) {
    override suspend fun deleteItemFromDatabase() {
        repository.deleteDay(day)
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work. It doesn't recognize viewModelScope and it doesn't recognize repository. `InfoItemViewModelImpl` is created before InfoDayViewModel and that's the reason why it can't access these properties. How can I solve it?

Comment: >Supose that the Lion class can only compute the age value inside an init block or another place but its constructor.

You mean it is impossible `class Lion(age: Int) : CanRun by CanRunImpl(age)`?

Comment: Yes, that is impossible in this example. I am working on a project that has this problem and I have tried to simplify it using this example.

Comment: It's not clear why you can't make `age` a constructor parameter. Could you provide a more specific example why you can't do that?

Comment: I created another question using the code that contains the real problem. That's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64650687/how-to-make-a-delegated-class-use-properties-of-the-class-that-delegates-it

Comment: Please edit the original question instead of opening a duplicate.

Comment: I edited this question to show the real problem and I deleted the duplicate that I shouldn't have created

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible workaround. It's less verbose than your solution if you're using this delegate in multiple classes. But it's not very elegant, since the `age` becomes a public read-write property.

```
interface CanRun {
    fun run(): String
    var age: Int
}

class CanRunImpl : CanRun {
    override var age by Delegates.notNull<Int>()
    override fun run(): String {
        return if (age > 10) "fast" else "slow"
    }
}

class Lion : CanRun by CanRunImpl() {
    init { age = 5 }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if that's the best way to solve my problem. I see that it works but you are forced to make the properties public.